# Dynamically add a bookmark on PDF.js Express Viewer

Tags: javascript

In my web application, I'm using the [PDF.js Express Viewer](https://pdfjs.express/documentation/get-started-viewer) library to preview a PDF file. Despite having read the documentation and made numerous attempts, I am having a hard time adding a [bookmark](https://pdfjs.express/api/Core.Bookmark.html) dynamically from code.

I couldn't find any examples online.
Any of you have experience on this?

Comment: Are you using pdf.js Express Viewer or pdf.js viewer.html? The link you provided is to Express Viewer, whose commands won't work with the github pdf.js [viewer](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/).

Comment: I'm using PDF.js Express Viewer (the one indicated in the link)